# Postgres Back up In Rancher(Kubernetes)

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes, containers, rancher

I have web application with Postgresql deployed on Rancher. What is the best backup strategy? What is the process of restoring a postgres database from the pg_dump in rancher?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Error is clearly states that there's not enough space. Have you checked a persistent volume? Node itself where kubernetes cluster is running?

Comment: All the persistent volumes are still "bound" and kubernetes cluster runs on AWS.  May be the EC2 instance where the Kubernetes cluster runs ran out of space?

Comment: You should check everything + logs/status of nodes. If node is running out of free space, then it won't be in ready status when `kubectl get nodes` is run. Also no information about what PV is used. It can be a cloud storage. Too many options to guess. Please update the question with all valuable information so community can help you, not guess.

Comment: I tried redeploying the workload with a different name ,but still got the same error in the pod.

Comment: @moonkotte i ran docker system prune -a -f . Still no effect